# Efficient/elegant way to use boolean operator on multiple columns of time stamps and

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time, boolean

I have a df structured as so:

```
    ID    DATE             T1                  T2                 T3
0  1000   5/5/2016  5/5/2016 3:58:54    5/5/2016 4:02:00   5/5/2016 4:15:05
1  1001   5/6/2016  5/5/2016 17:23:39   5/5/2016 17:24:00  5/5/2016 17:44:32
2  1002   5/7/2016  5/5/2016 18:20:50   5/5/2016 18:22:00  5/5/2016 18:37:34
3  1003   5/7/2016  5/5/2016 21:30:29   5/5/2016 21:35:00  5/5/2016 21:45:51
4  1004   5/9/2016  5/5/2016 22:33:19   5/5/2016 22:34:00  5/5/2016 22:41:54
```

I want to identify times in T2 and T3 that are before T1. If T2 or T3 occur before T1, then I want to add one day to T2/T3.

The first problem I have run into is reading a boolean array that will allow me to identify which records in T2 and T3 occur before T1. I can do this for a single column with:

```
idx = pd.to_datetime(df['T1'])<pd.to_datetime(df['T2'])
```

But if I try to do this with multiple columns using:

```
idx = pd.to_datetime(df['T1'])<pd.to_datetime(df['T2':])
```

gives me the following error:

```
TypeError: cannot do slice indexing on <class 'pandas.indexes.range.RangeIndex'> with these indexers [T2] of <class 'str'>
```

Once this issue is figured out, then I need to add one day to the times that are `True` with something like:

```
pd.DatetimeIndex(df['T2':'T3'].loc(idx)) + pd.DateOffset(1)
```

But, I have not been able to play around with this part yet, so some help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC:

```
df.loc[:, ['T2', 'T3']] = \
    df[['T2', 'T3']].add(
        pd.to_timedelta(((df.T2 < df.T1) | (df.T3 < df.T1)).astype(int), 'd'), 0)
```

Comment: Hmmm. I am getting this error: `TypeError: ufunc add cannot use operands with types dtype('O') and dtype('<m8[ns]')`

Comment: @user2970409 I'm guessing not all columns are datetime.  You can ensure that they are with `df['mycolumn'] = pd.to_datetime(df['mycolumn'])`

Comment: That works. Thanks! Btw, I think I understand all of this except the zero at the end. What is that doing? Axis?

Comment: The way I produced a boolean series and converted it to integers, when I add it back, I use the `axis=0` parameter option to specify that I'm adding this series to each column of the dataframe being operated on.  That `0` is the same as `axis=0`.